# Get current view in ui-router as a condition in controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to set

```
if (myArray.length === 0 && currentView === whatIWant) {
  // change current view
}
```

but I couldn't find nowhere what's the way to get the current view, any help?

Comment: you can get state name with $state.current.name

Comment: what do you mean by current view here?, name of the view?

Comment: Yes, name of the view

Answer (score 0):

You can use, `$state.current` and it has many methods in it.

```
(function(myApp) {
  'use strict';

  myApp.controller('MyController', MyController);

  /** @ngInject */
  function MyController($scope,$state) {

      $scope.current_state = $state.current.name

      if (myArray.length === 0 && ($scope.current_state) === whatIWant) {
          $state.go('state_name')
      }

    };



})(myApp);
```

[Here is the reference](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/0.3.1/#/api/ui.router.state.$state)

Comment: Thank you for replying. Here's a NOT working [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/KA2UMUfovQ8heKIp9MEj) to let you see what I'm doing wrong. Basically, I'm using Foundation for apps (it uses ui-router) and I'm getting "dettagli is not defined" error. Have in mind that I've cut out a lot from that plnkr, just uploaded the interested code.

Comment: Those routes don't appear to be ui-router structure (at least from my last year's worth of experience). Are you doing something with it to get it to work?

Comment: Well, [they say](http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/docs/#!/angular) they built a plugin based upon ui-router, if you're saying it's not ui-router structure I'm confused and don't know what to do.